How to avoid the need to map fields to columns without scan errors
I need to get records from an already existing legacy sqlserver database. The database has a lot of columns that are not needed for my use case. Therefore there is a mismatch between

the # of fields on type MyTable struct (1 field for each column)
and # of columns some queries select (SELECT a,b,c FROM MY_TABLE)

This causes

scan error: sql: expected 7 destination arguments in Scan, not 32

I already understand the cause (see 1 or 2) and fixed it.
// Retrieves orders from the database
func GetOrders(ctx context.Context, db *sql.DB, minID int)([]models.Order, error)
{
    query := "SELECT ORDER_ID, ORDER_UUID, NAME, ORDER_DATE
              FROM ORDER 
              WHERE ORDER_ID > @p1"
    rows, err := db.QueryContext(ctx, query, minID)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("query execution failed: %v", err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    var orders []models.Order
    for rows.Next() {
        var order models.Order
        receiver := []interface{}{&order.ORDER_ID, 
                                  &order.ORDER_UUID, 
                                  &order.NAME, 
                                  &order.ORDER_DATE}
        if err := rows.Scan(receiver...); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("error scanning row: %v", err)
        }
        orders = append(orders, order)
    }

    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error fetching orders: %v", err)
    }
    return orders, nil
}

But instead of writing all this mapping
receiver1 := []interface{}{&order.ORDER_ID, 
                                  &order.ORDER_UUID
receiver2 := []interface{}{&emp.Id, &emp.LAST_NAMEm
                                  &emp.FIRST_NAME

for each function (GetOrders(), GetEmployees(), GetCustomer(), ...) i would like to use this function from the wiki/SQLInterface
func GetTable[T any](rows *sql.Rows) (out []T) {
    var table []T
    for rows.Next() {
        var data T
        s := reflect.ValueOf(&data).Elem()
        numCols := s.NumField()
        columns := make([]interface{}, numCols)

        for i := 0; i < numCols; i++ {
            field := s.Field(i)
            columns[i] = field.Addr().Interface()
        }

        if err := rows.Scan(columns...); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Case Read Error ", err)
        }

        table = append(table, data)
    }
    return table
}

like this

orders := GetTable[Order]('SELECT A,B,Region FROM ORDER Group BY Region, A, B)

employees := GetTable[Employee]('SELECT Firstname,Lastname,City FROM Employee)


without the need to map the fields of a struct (Order, Employee) to every column i select in sql.
Questions

How can the boilerplate code to map fields of struct be mapped to columns of the SQL Select be avoided without using an orm like gorm?


I'm kinda thinking that SQL Server expertise isn't required for this?

Usually most drivers provide a metadata for a resultset, can't you use it to remove the values from columns-array or whatever it is which doesn't have a matching metadata column

There's some serious X-Y problem vibes here. Why would you even think that you can cast a *sql.Rows into a []T in a "generic way" (whatever that means). A *sql.Rows isn't a slice to begin with. Avoiding multiple DTO's  just sounds like either you're deperately trying to extract things too much, or you're dealing with a malformed schema. Different types of data require different representations, hence distinct DTO's.

My wording is not ideal. What i mean is that i want to use the same getTable[T any] function but for different types (example getTable[Order](rows) or  getTable[Customer](rows). My intention is to create a type for each table (Order, 'Customer`) but not different "subtypes" OrderForView_1, OrderForView_2.

@EliasVanOotegem i have updated the question. Does this make it clearer?
